# How to transfer a file from Windows to Linux server using samba share?

Tags: linux, putty, samba

I'm facing a nightmare at work. A colleague responsible for what I'm going to describe below handed this responsibility to me and has now left the organization. I have no experience doing any of this stuff. Please excuse my lack of knowledge and long question-I'm not sure what info to include/leave out.

### **Background**

We procure some data from a third party, which is sent to a postgres server and then brought into a linux server where some shell scripts do some transformations. The dataset is then combined, after which it is sent to a data analysis tool we use. The process is automated using cron.

However, every year, we need to manually update some metadata csv files on the linux server [these are combined with the 3rd party data using a shell script].

### Folder structure:

Below is what the linux server folder structure looks like [accessed using PuTTY]:

- another_project
- another_project
- **my_project**
- another_project

~/my_project>

- shell_scripts
- procured_files
- **meta_files**
- combined_files

~/meta_files>

- 2019.csv
- 2020.csv
- 2021.csv

### What I need to do

What I need to do is add a file called **2022.csv** to the meta_files folder. I have the file on my local system. In my colleague's handover document, he simply says to "copy the file to linux using samba share". I've found the samba share location and set it up on my windows explorer. It has an address that looks like this: **\\smb.comp.com\prod**. There are various sorts of folders in here.

I suspect that I've got to place the **2022.csv** file somewhere in the samba share and then run a command on the linux server using PuTTY. However, I've no idea where to put it and what command to run.

I apologize again for such a long question and the excessive description. Any help with how I can get the 2022.csv file onto linux would be greatly appreciated. Please let me know if any other info is required. Many thanks.

Comment: Samba share works as a network share in Windows. So you just copy the file there as any other file in Windows. Open `\\smb.comp.com\prod` in Windows Explorer and drag&drop your file there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are already using SSH to access the Linux server, do it the other way around – connect to the Linux server via SFTP to directly *upload* the file. Generally, all servers that accept SSH also accept SFTP connections.

- PuTTY comes with the `pscp` and `psftp` commands (which can use your existing SSH keys and everything).

  ```
  C:\> pscp 2022.csv user@yourserver:~/my_project/meta_files/2022.csv
  ```
- Recent Windows versions come with OpenSSH built-in, with the `scp` and `sftp` commands. Their usage is similar to pscp/psftp.
- WinSCP is a good graphical SFTP client, but also has a batch CLI mode (`winscp.com`) and a .NET assembly for automation.
- For manual GUI usage, I think Bitvise has SFTP as well. FileZilla will also do.

But if the Linux server *must* pull the file from the SMB share – put it wherever you want, then use a Linux SMB client to access it. There are several, for example:

- The `smbclient` command from Samba. Good for one-time jobs but unpleasant to automate:

  ```
  $ smbclient //smb.comp.com/prod -U someuser
  smbclient> get 2022.csv
  ```
- Kernel-level `smb3` and `cifs` mounts. Good choice for automation but require root privileges on the Linux system to set up for the first time.

  ```
  $ sudo mount -t smb3 //smb.comp.com/prod /mnt/thesmbserver [options...]
  $ cp -av /mnt/thesmbserver/2022.csv ~/my_project/meta_files/
  $ sudo umount /mnt/thesmbserver
  ```

  (If the SMB share does not support SMB3, use the older `cifs` type.)
- A custom Python script using the "python-smbprotocol" module. Good for automation:

  ```
  import os
  import shutil
  import smbclient
  import time

  thisyear = time.strftime("%Y")
  remote = r"\\smb.comp.com\prod\%s.csv" % thisyear
  local = os.path.expanduser("~/my_project/meta_files/%s.csv" % thisyear)

  with smbclient.open_file(remote, "rb") as remote_fh:
      with open(local, "wb") as local_fh:
          shutil.copyfileobj(remote_fh, local_fh)
  ```

(We have several Linux cronjobs that use python-smbprotocol to copy files *to* Windows servers and then python-pypsrp to remotely run commands on those Windows systems.)

Comment: Many, many thanks for your response. I tried using the smbclient command, but get a "connection to smb.comp.com failed (ERROR NT_STATUS_IO_TIMEOUT)" error when I try entering my password. I'll need to look into what might be causing this.

Comment: Most likely a firewall.